# Tensorflow Model does not work after loading parameters

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, conv-neural-network

I have a Tensorflow model that has been trained and saved successfully. Then I used it for a while, with no change to anything of the model or the environment. Now, after two month I am running the same model on the same data and it is giving results way worst than what is was before.

Has anyone had any similar experience with the Tensorflow?

I thought there are some changes to the environement perhaps that is causing this issue, so I installed the Tensorflow 2.5, CuDNN 8.1, and CUDA 11.2 as required by the original environment and tested the model again, however, it fails again.

I also tested it by Tensorflow 2.11, it fails in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This happens mainly due to data drift which is input data changes when the model inference happens.

Data drift refers to changes in the distribution or characteristics of the input data over time, and it can significantly impact a model's performance.

It occurs when the statistical properties of the data deviate from those observed during the model's training phase. It is crucial to verify that the current input data remains representative of the data the model was originally trained on to ensure the model's continued effectiveness.

Evaluating and addressing potential data drift involves monitoring the input data distribution and adapting the model as needed to accommodate any shifts, thus maintaining its reliability in evolving real-word scenarios.